# Calculate sum of duration SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I use the following sql to calculate the duration in the first query.

```sql
CDate(TimeSerial(Val([EndTime])\100,Val([EndTime]) Mod 100,0)-TimeSerial(Val([StartTime])\100,Val([StartTime]) Mod 100,0))) AS Duration
```

And get the following which is good [image]

And now, I would like to further calculate the total time of different lessons within a week in another query. Something like sum(iif(lesson="math",duration,0))

But since it's time data type sql server doesn't let me use the sum function.

I tried the following sql.

```sql
sum(hour(duration) + minute(duration)) AS Total_time
```

But it isn't what I expect because I would like to keep the original format with some criteria.

Is there a neat way to do so? Thank you.

Comment: What's in your time fields? You pretty much never want to `Val` a date or time field

Comment: string, like 1330 to 1530

Comment: It sounds like this question actually boils down to: How do I format a date with more than 24 hours as Hours:Days. Is that correct?

Comment: not really. The problem is that is there an easy way to sum over the duration in the format of hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, just get the numeric duration:

```
TimeSerial(Val([EndTime])\100,Val([EndTime]) Mod 100,0)-TimeSerial(Val([StartTime])\100,Val([StartTime]) Mod 100,0) AS Duration
```

This you can sum and convert to DateTime:

```
CDate(Sum([duration])) AS Total_time
```

**Example**:

Data:

[image: Data]

Queries:

```sql
SELECT 
    StartTime, 
    EndTime, 
    TimeSerial(Val([EndTime])\100,Val([EndTime]) Mod 100,0)-TimeSerial(Val([StartTime])\100,Val([StartTime]) Mod 100,0) AS Duration
FROM 
    tTest;
```

```sql
SELECT 
    Count(*) AS Slots, 
    CDate(Sum([Duration])) AS TotalHours
FROM 
    qTest;
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: It certainly does. See extended answer, please.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend just accepting the total time in seconds or decimal hours:

```
select datediff("s", starttime, endtime) as diff_seconds,
       datediff("s", starttime, endtime) / (60 * 60.0) as diff_hours
```

Comment: starttime and endtime are string

Comment: @user13851309 . . . Convert them to date/times then for the `datediff()`.

Comment: I change the question a bit which was confusing. I wanna calculate the total time in another query based on the duration.